# How to Count the total number of pages in a EPUB file using PHP for all the EPUB format

Tags: php, epub

I am working on the EPUB reader application and I want to restrict the user to read some of the pages in epub preview and for same I need to determine the total number of pages in epub at run time.

Some epub files are providing the page count but some epub format are not.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I have tried using php but some epub not providing the page count in xml so for that i want to find total page count.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542479/count-total-number-of-pages-in-epub/ . Also read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542479/count-total-number-of-pages-in-epub/40561575#40561575 about the fact that "page" is not well defined in the case of reflowable EPUB files.

Comment: Anyway, for your purpose you can just count the number of characters in the text of the XHTML files in the spine of the EPUB, and allow browsing up to X % for your preview. That's the (crude) way most EPUB previewers work. Note that there is an official EPUB specification ( http://www.idpf.org/epub/previews/ ) that let authors specify a portion of an EPUB publication as its "preview", but of course no one is using it, so it does not help in your case.