# How do i can to avoid this error in Flutter EpubViewer?

Tags: flutter, manifest

/home/unical-4/AndroidStudioProjects/book/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:32:9-42:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.folioreader.ui.activity.SearchActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

I am using [Epub viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/epub_viewer)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin that you are using is already discontinued better switch to a new package.  Something like https://pub.dev/packages/epub_view

Comment: How can i get pageCount in this package ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542479/count-total-number-of-pages-in-epub